# Loading embedded iframe with same protocol as window top to prevent Same Origin Policy Violation

Tags: javascript, sdk, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, easyxdm

We're developing a Javascript SDK which is used by embedded applications (injected in my site as IFRAMEs) to help them use some resources like loading some dialogs: e.g. an authorization dialog or a share box(like Facebook).

Our SDK is using easyXDM to work more or less like this:

**HTML Page** 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| http / https: **www.mysite.com**/embedded-app/ 
| (Some JS classes)
| 
|- - - - - | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|- - - - - | (IFRAME)
|- - - - - | https: // **www.some-embedded-app-domain.com**/page.html
|- - - - - | (loads and instantiates the SDK from "http/https:www.mysite.com/sdk.js that uses easyXDM)
|- - - - - |
|- - - - - | - - - - - |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|- - - - - | - - - - - | (IFRAME injected by easyXDM)
|- - - - - | - - - - - | http / https: **www.mysite.com**/embedded_provider.html 
|- - - - - | - - - - - | (Communication with window.top to talk to use those wndow.top JS classes) 
|- - - - - | - - - - - | 
|- - - - - | - - - - - | 
|- - - - - | - - - - - | 
|- - - - - | - - - - - |

My site can be loaded both using http/https, but the embedded application must be served using **always** HTTPS. In order to allow the inner iframe injected by easyXDM to communicate with my site, the host and protocol **must match** in both urls, otherwise a same origin policy violation will arise.

Problem: how would I tell the code from the SDK, which is loaded from an external app URL, that the outer windows (my site) is using http or https, to render the embedded_provider.html using the same protocol and thus allowing JS communication between both of them?

The only solution I can think of is to inform the embedded app somehow that we're currently browsing from http / https, and then it can instantiate it properly (using a flag use_https or so), but I'd prefer to not force the App to know the protocol we are using.

Do you know any other alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Use // instead http:// or https://

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of (haven't tested this though), is to have easyXDM put in 2 test iframes - one on http://www.mysite.com/url_test and one on https://www.mysite.com/url_test.

Then have your /url_test webpage try to access window.top.location.href.  If /url_test can see the location, then it must be on the same domain.  Then the successfull /url_test page will communicate to the parent iframe (on some-embedded-app.com) via easyXDM to create the iframe you really want on the correct host.

Note: the /url_test page which is on the incorrect host will start to dump same-origin iframe warnings in the console. :)

Note #2: if this approach works, you could iteratively improve it by saying, "because of the product domain, i know that 80% of these embeds will be on http.  I'll make a /url_test on http first, then try https as a backup."

Answer (score 0):

Use // instead http:// or https://

The browser will sort it out

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work, since the 1st IFRAME is loaded always on HTTPS (and thus the "//" will be always resolved as https), but the outer most window may be on HTTP.